# Calculate total resistance and current flowing through the circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

For both problems, provide both volts and ohms.
[image]

[image: First attempt at solving][image: Second attempt at solving]

Comment: This is not a homework solving service. Let us know what you have done so far to solve it, and where you are stuck.

Comment: Homework questions with no attempt at a solution get closed very quickly. Show your work and ask about where you get stuck.

Comment: Smells like homework, without even a whiff of an effort to solve.

Comment: I’m attempting to help my brother out on an assignment that his teacher won’t talk him through it. I don’t know where to start or what to ask.

Comment: @Transistor thanks for the direction. We're new to this.

Comment: For question 2b, the total resistance is not the sum of all the resistors - you have two resistors in series, one in parallel with those two, and another in series with the previous three.  I don't see how you calculated the current as 1.78 Amp.

Comment: Take special note of how Transistor drew each little step of the solving process. This is a **great** habit to develop. You'd think it means more work, but ultimately it's less work because it eliminates all those pesky do-overs! (Also, even if you do make a mistake along the way, it's really easy to find and correct it if you have all the steps drawn like this).

Answer (score 4):

Your approach is not correct.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fofEdU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2b. Simplify.*

- The trick is to add any series resistors where you can.
- Then "add" the parallel resistors using the parallel resistor formula that you have (but used incorrectly).
- Repeat until you've got it down to the battery and one resistor.

Sanity check: when you series resistors the result should be greater than either resistor on its own. When you parallel resistors the result should be less than either on its own.

Can you solve it now?

---

The schematics were created using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip.

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Answer (score 0):

@Transistor showed showed the simplification steps, but I find the circuit is easier to see if drawn like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCYgL4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The circuits used in this sort of exercise are often drawn in a way designed to confuse the student.  Re-drawing the circuit with the power source on the left, positive supply on the top, and negative supply on the bottom generally makes it easier to work out the method required to simplify the circuit (and you'll find most real circuits are laid out this way).

Answer (score -1):

[image: these are the answers I got based on the feedback from the original]
these are the answers I got based on the feedback from the original

Comment: Your answer is wrong.  For question 2b, you forgot the two 10 Ohm resistors in series that are in parallel with the 9 Ohm. In 2C, you neglected the 7 + 4 Ohm resistors in parallel with the 10 Ohm.